Improper `at' size due to newtx
Suddenly, I'm getting this error message when using newtx:
Improper `at' size (0.0pt), replaced by 10pt.

Here is a minimal example where this happens:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\begin{document}
This is \textsf{sans serif}.
\end{document}

The problem is caused by \textsf. Note that if I change from newtx to txfonts, the problem goes away.
I was having no problems yesterday, so I suspect something bad happened when I updated TeXLive packages.

hm, newtx managed to set \qhv@scale to zero. That is a bug, write the maintainer.

the problems seems to be that newtx changed \newcommand*{\ntxtext@scale}{1} into \newcommand*{\ntxtext@scale}{0}.

Thank you! I don't know how to contact the author ... Can you do it or tell me how?

One way to contact the author of a package: go to CTAN and find the package there (https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) there you can find the author's mail address (https://ctan.org/home/msharpe). It seems that no contact information is given in the package manual though.

I filed a report to the maintainer.

The bug seems to have been fixed!

Update 2024-06-25
Version 1.751 of newtx seems to have fixed the issue.
Older answer for a workaround
For some reason, the new version (1.75) of newtx.sty says
\newcommand*{\ntxtext@scale}{0}

where it used to have
\newcommand*{\ntxtext@scale}{1}

However, the change doesn't take into account that the package has
      \renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{qhv}
      \@tempdima=\ntxtext@scale\p@
      \@tempdima=\tx@helvratio\@tempdima%
      \edef\qhv@scale{\strip@pt\@tempdima}

so with the new version \qhv@scale gets defined to 0, which is a bad value when ot1qhv.fd or t1qhv.fd gets to be loaded.
Until the bug is fixed, you can tell newtx not to load tgheros and do it yourself.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nohelv]{newtx}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{tgheros}
\begin{document}
This is \textsf{sans serif}.
\end{document}



I filed a report to the maintainer.

The maintainer answered saying that a fix is expected soon.
